# Virtualizing Mac OS X on Linux - is it legal?

Tags: macos, virtualization, unix

While browsing i found an interesting [tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mac-on-linux/) in sourceforge.net
it says

> Mac-on-Linux is a Linux/PPC program that virtualizes Mac OS or Mac OS X in Linux.

Is it legal In india?

Comment: Legal is a very hard question for any internet site since what may be considered acceptable in one country is not at all equivalent in another. Would you mind editing this to ask what the license agreement says - that can be answered much better than whether that license applies in a binding legal manner for location X.

Comment: It's not legal anywhere. Apple does not license their OS to any vendor and only permits running it on Apple hardware owned by the individual.

Comment: @cksum: It's not *permitted by Apple*.  But the fact that Apple doesn't want you to do something doesn't make it illegal.  Laws are what do that, and some countries might have laws that would render Apple's restrictions unenforceable.

Comment: @cHao Yes, you are right. Legality is not the same thing as a EULA. However, going by the precedent set from the Apple vs. Psystar case some years back, where Apple used several arguments to prevent them from installing OS X on non-Apple products. In particular, Apple's lawyers spoke of the requirement to circumvent OS X's encryption that allows it to only install on approved Apple hardware in such cases was required (and deemed illegal). If anything, Apple could sue (unlikely in this case), but legally speaking, this question is unanswerable unless put through due process. I vote to close.

Comment: @cksum
David posted the answer

Comment: @cksum, The case of Apple vs. Pystar is a legal case in the **United States**. Other countries' law may treat it differently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Apple hardware, yes - [as of OSX Lion / Lion Server](http://www.macrumors.com/2011/07/01/os-x-lion-allows-running-multiple-copies-on-the-same-machine-virtualization/).  Otherwise, no - it's a violation of the EULA.

Comment: The next question is whether this EULA is binding in India. A tricky question that only a local lawyer can answer (if at all). I’m pretty sure that this clause wouldn’t be binding in Germany, for instance. (If you’ve legally acquired the OS X license, that is.)

Answer (score 3):

It's a violation if its not on apple hardware. For the record that is for OS X ppc only. It doesn't work with anything recent at all.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks i got solution from [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109999/mac-on-linux-is-it-legal)

> It's against the EULA, but in general, each provision of a EULA is
>   treated separately (at least, according to Wikipedia), i.e. so a part
>   of a EULA might be found to be legally non-binding. The legality
>   depends on where you are, but if you're in the US, I would guess it's
>   illegal because of the DMCA. Apple sued a clone manufacturer(Psystar)
>   several years ago for selling machines with OS X installed on them.
>   They sued under several different legal reasons, but one of them was
>   that Apple uses encryption methods protected under the DMCA to keep OS
>   X from being installed on non-Apple hardware. The court found that
>   indeed the DMCA was violated and Apple won.
>   via [cs](https://askubuntu.com/users/43660/c-s)

Answer (score -2):

It is a violation but it runs so crappy if your using VirtualBox anyway (also no guest additions) that you couldn't do anything worth while in it anyway.

there is alot of graphics problems and it makes the OS pretty much unusable.